# IOS and Android emulator for windows 10 using react native

Tags: android, ios, windows-10, emulator

I'm currently looking for an Ios and Android emulator where i could test my react-native app on windows 10. I can run android studio emulator for android but is there a software where i could test my app on both ios and android at the same time?

Comment: If you don't mind the costs, a service like https://www.browserstack.com
 could come in very handy. It allows you to test many OS/Browser combionations.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run both **`Android`** and **`IOS`** at the same time with emulators, but you can use **`Virtual Box`** or **`Virtual Machine`**. I use and recommend **`Oracle Virtual Box`**. Just install **`Oracle Virtual Box`**, download **`Android`** and **`IOS`** `system images` and use them. See `tutorials` for how to use `VM` (`Virtual Box`).

Download links:

[Android System Image](https://www.osboxes.org/android-x86/)

[Oracle Virtual Box](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/virtualbox/downloads/index.html)

**Note:** Unfortunately, there isn't any `system images` for `Virtual Box` officially.